# IIS forms auth using PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

I have a website with PHP and 3 different .Net apps in 3 different subfolders. All is working well.

The PHP app has authentication builtin with ye old "include security_check.php" on top. The PHP app also has the user editor (logins) and is the star of the show.

I would like to extend the PHP security scheme to include the .Net apps. To do this I am thinking something in the direction of a web.config placed in the root with .Net forms auth configured. This should include all subfolders.

1. How would this affect web.config inheritence in subfolders?
2. Can I use PHP to handle the logins directly? 
   Or do I have to use ASPX to check for cookie containing username (set on successful auth in PHP), then redirect to PHP login if it is missing?